# Migrating from EditPad Classic to EditPad Lite, simple question

Tags: windows, compatibility, editpad

I have been using EditPad since it first version (I don't remember what postcard I sent).  I tried EditPad Lite when it was announced and had the problem I am writing about, but the original was working so I never changed.  Once I started (not really voluntarily) using Windows 10, EditPad became wonky.  It would start some days, but not others, I would have to change the compatibility almost daily. With the latest update to Windows 10 it seems to be gone forever.

So -- my question, to which I have been unable to find any answer.  In EditPad Lite, what is the equivalent in Find/Replace for \n and \t?  I have spent a day on Google without finding the answer.  I know this is late in time, but this seems like a reasonable place to ask.

What I did on my summer vacation:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling (which amounts to deleting the .exe file and recopying it from backup to Program Files (x86)).  Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.
2. Running through all the compatibility settings available, both on desktop icons and on the .exe file.  Again, sometimes things worked for a day, even weeks, the the program would fail to open.  (The general symptom would be the circular progress indicator spinning a few times and then vanishing, with the program not opening.)
3. Trying to open by clicking on a desktop icon, on the .exe stored in Program Files (x86), clicking on a copy of the .exe in some other location and on some other hard drive.
4. Recently, after an update, the check box and drop-down list of version in the compatibility tab of the Properties window (for the icons on the desktop, pinned to the toolbar, and the .exe file) are grayed out and only the Troubleshoot procedure is available.  (I should note that the "Run this program..." box seems to be locked at "Windows 98 / Windows Me", and "save" in the troubleshooter doesn't change that, nor is it one of the options offered by the troubleshooter.)  At this point nothing I do has awakened the program.  I have tried all the offered possibilities in the Troubleshooter, to no avail.
5. I have spent hours in Google, with the only glimmers of light being some discussions of Regex, about which I know nothing.  (I'm an old System 360/370 assembler language programmer, and a LISP programmer.  I never even learned C!)  Can anyone here give me a simple solution?  Or should I wipe the damn C: drive and install Windows 7, or maybe XP?

After reading one of the proffered question/answer posts it appears that the solution will indeed involve Redex.  I guess I either need a "type these strings" answer or a pointer to someplace that will teach me enough of this language to at least know how to parse the strings.  And people complain about LISP code?????